# What's the quickest/easiest way to make a digital signature on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation

I need to scribble my signature on an electronic document. I see that [Google Drawings](https://docs.google.com/drawings) has a scribble feature, but I can't get a mouse to produce anything that looks like my written signature.

[image]

I can't seem to find this option in Google Drive for iOS (there's no "New Drawing" option). I'm not sure if it's buried in another app or if I can use it on the mobile website.

I'm willing to try other methods, if they're readily available in iOS 10 (native feature, Apple apps, or something not requiring an account or registration).

Comment: Why not just try it? Presumably you have an iPad to hand.

Comment: I fixed up the question to be more general and to explain that I can't find the feature on the iPad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Email the document to yourself, then tap the icon of the attachment. When you do this, it should open, and a small toolbox should be in the top right hand corner. Tap it, and you may add a signature using the signature button at the bottom left corner. There are dedicated apps available on the App Store, like [HelloSign](https://appsto.re/ca/CC0JG.i). Furthermore, macOS "Preview" App also allows for the signing of documents, as does Adobe Reader DC.

For signing on Mac, follow instructions that may be found [here](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/digitally-sign-a-pdf-using-preview-on-mac/), which basically says to click on the toolbox icon within preview, then the signature icon located in the menu that just dropped down.

*Footnotes:*

[1] The document must be a PDF and on iOS, it must be opened from the mail app.

[2] The newest OS is recommended to perform these actions, but it is available on iOS 9 and later. And macOS must be 10.9 or above.

Best of luck!